# How to Compare String value with List box value using c#?

Tags: c#

in my code i want to check my string value with List Box value,in my list box i have 3 value,
thing is i don't want to choose string in List box like(selected.items.text)

exactly my problem like this,

```
String name="asdf",List Box value={"aaaa","asdf","BBBB"}

check like if(listbox.itms,tostring()="asdf")
{
}
```

thanks for Advance

Comment: Have you ever read a book about C#? Because these are not valid syntax.

Comment: try to start  with  this first http://www.learncs.org/

Comment: @user1746934 you should foreach every element thta you have "value" and then check if it's equals than (in that case asdf)

Comment: First Read my passage fully,i am gave only example not Syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for `Contains` method

```
listBox.Items.Contains(name);
```

Comment: yes exactly i am looking for this kind of things only,i am really wonder about your way of code,thanks for your future help

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure of your syntax above.  You say this is a C# question, but that doesn't look like valid C#.  Anyway, the following should tell you if the string is in a ListBox:

```
listbox.Items.Contains(name);
```

Comment: Maybe because someone else beat me to the answer by a few seconds?

Comment: Possibly but that isn't a valid reason for the downvoter, hopefully they will explain

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code:

```
foreach (ListItem li in lbTest.Items)
 {
 li.Value.Equals("string to check with");
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Try this:

    foreach(string item in value){
       if (item.Equal(name))
          return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        var items = listbox.Items;
        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            if (item.ToString() == "asdf")
            {
                 //Your Statement
            }
        }
```